# Android MVVM - How to make LiveData emits the data it has (forcing to trigger the observer)

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm, android-livedata

I have this `ViewModel` that gets a list from the network and I populate a `RecyclerView` with the data (`MyAvailabilityRepository` returns a `MutableLiveData`, that's why i'm using `Transformations.switchMap`):

```
class MyAvailabilityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val getListsParams = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val getListsObservable = Transformations.switchMap(getListsParams) { 
        organizationId -> MyAvailabilityRepository.getSectionedLists(organizationId) 
    }

    fun getListsObservable() : LiveData<Resource<MutableList<SectionedAvailabilityList>>> {
        return getListsObservable
    }

    fun fetchLists(organizationId: String, forceRefresh: Boolean = false) {
        if (getListsParams.value == null || forceRefresh) {
            getListsParams.value = organizationId
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment's `onActivityCreated`:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    viewModel.getListsObservable().observe(this, Observer { // populate RecyclerView })
    viewModel.fetchLists(organizationId)
}
```

Since `getListParams.value` is null the first time, it will set `getListsParams.value = organizationId` and trigger the `switchMap` and call the repository to get the list from the network.

When I want to force a refresh (by pull-to-refresh) and call the network again, I can use `forceRefresh = true`:

```
override fun onRefresh() {
    viewModel.fetchLists(organizationId, forceRefresh = true)
}
```

It will set the value of `organizationId` and trigger the Transformations that will then call network.

But, I have a scenario where I clear the data from my RecyclerView's adapter. If after that, the user click a button, I would like to trigger the observer again so that I re-populate the adapter with the data that the getListsObservable has already fetched. I don't want to call forceRefresh on this one cause i'm sure I already have the data and I would just like to trigger the observer again so that my UI is updated with the existing data. Since `getListParams.value` is not null at that point, then nothing happens when I call `fetchLists(organizationId)` later on.

Any idea of how I could achieve that with my current setup?

Answer (score 29):

Yes, the answer given by Hong Duan is perfect.
 I am just going to extend that answer here,

The better way of doing is having an extension function.

My extension function looks like this,

```
fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.forceRefresh() {
    this.value = this.value
}
```

Caller function looks like this,

```
mutableLiveDataObject.forceRefresh()
```

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 5):

Try `removeObservers()` and `observe()` again:

```
viewModel.getListsObservable().removeObservers(this)
viewModel.getListsObservable().observe(this, Observer { // populate RecyclerView })
```

because:

> If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E)).

Or maybe you can change the `getListsObservable()` to return a `MutableLiveData`, then call `setValue` manually:

```
fun loadCurrentData() {
    getListsObservable.value = getListsObservable.value
}
```

Comment: The first one helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do force refresh by this approach -

```
if (mainViewModel.mutable != null && mainViewModel.mutable.getValue()) {
    mainViewModel.mutable.setValue(mainViewModel.mutable.getValue());
}
```