# Room - LiveData unnecessary when reading data only once?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am following this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) and one of the suggested best practices for retrieving data from a database was to use a `LiveData` wrapper for my `DAO` return values (step 6 in the codelab).

But in my app, I am reading an existing `.sqlite` file only once at the start of the activity. Thus using this wrapper should be unnecessary, am I correct?

So is it acceptable (in terms of best practices) to make my `DAO` return a simple object instead of using the `LiveData` construct around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two features of `LiveData`: delivery of updates and asynchronous operation.

If you will not be changing the data during the run of your app, you will not take advantage of the update-delivery feature of `LiveData`.

However, you still need to arrange to load the data on a background thread. If you plan on doing that by some other means (e.g., RxJava, your own background thread), you could avoid using `LiveData`.

Also, if your plan is to load all of the data in the database at the outset and never change it, then SQLite and Room are pointless. Just use a JSON file. The value in SQLite is in being able to query and modify parts of the data.

Comment: Two points: **1)** You are correct with that last point, however I have two activities using two different tables in the db. So the other one does use insert and delete operations. **2)** As to the other point, it's true, I still need the data loading on a background thread. What would be the correct way of doing it only once? I thought of simply triggering the observer manually, but the suggested answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073400/1972372) is not very good looking. Any resource or link to an explanation would help.

Comment: The problem was that I assumed the `onChanged` method of the observer did not fire initially. Further testing revealed that it was an IO issue with the file. So my question about doing it once became obsolete, as I can simply do that in this method. I guess I can consider my initial question answered by this though.

Comment: @Big_Chair: "What would be the correct way of doing it only once?" -- if you are using RxJava, have your DAO return a `Single`. If you are using Kotlin coroutines, you may be able to have your DAO query function be a `suspend fun`. Otherwise, have the DAO just return the data, and do something else to call that DAO method on a background thread. Or, just use `LiveData`, which I am guessing is what you settled on.